# How do the 'bugs' and 'reqs' tabs work?

Tags: support, tags

Just curious... How do the 'bugs' and 'reqs' tabs work?

Do they just show the highest voted bugs and feature requests that don't have specific status-* tags? To basically show the highest voted *possible to be implemented/fixed* stuff?

That's what it seems so, but then why are [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) posts still shown in the bugs tab?

Is there a set 'filter' that is mentioned anywhere? What are the 'specific' tags that are excluded?

Comment: I suspect the [tag:status-norepro] being included is a bug. Can't know for sure though. :/

Comment: Guess these tabs give bugs/reqs without completed, declined or by design tags.

Comment: Huh, what "tabs", where are they?

Comment: @ChristianRau On the Meta (only on Meta) homepage at the top. http://i.stack.imgur.com/8K0Ng.png

Comment: [Blog post regarding these tabs](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/05/14/new-top-bugs-and-top-requests-on-meta/), written back when they were implemented for the first time

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The two are basically equivalent to the following tag searches, then sorted by votes:

reqs: `feature-request -status-completed -status-declined -status-deferred`
bugs: `bug -status-completed -status-declined -status-deferred -status-bydesign`

I don't know why [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)/[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) aren't excluded... could be an oversight, but on the other hand, it may be useful to have additional eyes on things that we couldn't reproduce or requests that are under review just in case we're wrong*.

<sub><sup>*</sup> It happens. Don't tell anyone.</sub>